# How to fix the logic problem in my loop for my basic logon screen

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, logic

I get the code to tell me when someone types in a bad userid or password. And I can get it to let people in when the get they type in the first userid and password

`user1` and `pass1`

But, if they try `user2` and `pass2` it says it is a wrong password. I know it is a logic error on my part with the loop, but, cant figure it out for the life of me! Please help me understand if you guys can!

Thank you

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Assignment 1</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/login.css">
</head>

<body>
<script>
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "grey";
    var valid = false;

    function validate() {
        var useArray = ["user1", "user2", "user3"];
        var passArray = ["pass1", "pass2", "pass3"];

        var x = document.login.userId.value;
        var y = document.login.passWord.value;

        for(var i = 0; i < useArray.length; i++) {
            if (x == useArray[i] && y == passArray[i]) {
                document.write("You have successfully logged on to your 
class!");
                return false;
            } else if (i = useArray.length - 1) {
                document.write("Error: User Id is not valid, please click the 
    link below again \n \n");
                var l =(" link back");
                var back = l.link("practice.html");
                document.write(back);
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
<div class="container">
    <h1>Logon</h1>
    <form name="login">
        <label for="useId">Userid: </label>    
        <input type="text" name="userId" required>
        <br><br>
        <label for="passWord">Password: </label>
        <input type="password" name="passWord" required>
        <br><br>
        <input type="button" class="submit" value="Log In" name="submit" 
  onclick="validate(this.form)">
  </form>
  </div>
  <br><br>

</body>
</html>
```

I need it to accept the other parts of the Array too. When someone puts in `usee2` and `pass2` for example

Thank you

Comment: You should NEVER put login details in the front end logic where anyone with a console can see them.

Comment: True, but this is just for a HW assignment, this is NOT for any sort of real world project.

Comment: Homework assingments that request you to do BAD practises are BAD homework assignments. There are any other number of ways to deminstrate validation of content from user input to a prefined set of values - asking you as a student to do it with usernames and passwords inhernetly tells you that you can do it and then when you get out into the 'real world' you may do it since you were taught to do it.

Comment: It's just a typo. `if (i = useArray.length - 1)` should use `==`, not `=`.

Answer (score 0):

You're having trouble over here `else if (i = useArray.length - 1)`
`useArray.length` is going to be 3 for all loops so `userArray.length - 1` will always eval to `2`, you're setting `i = 2` inside the `if`
in JS the assignment operator also returns the value assigned so you're basically writing
`else if( 2 )` which will always evaluate to `true`